# R- Grep dataframe for string and conditionally add new value based on search result for each row

Tags: r, apply

I have the following dataframes

`Search dataframe`

```
     EC              name
1    2.1.1.233       helicase
2    4.1.3.3         phosphatase
3    1.3.2.1,2.5.4.1 lipase
```

`query dataframe`

```
     PDB     EC         
1    1uay    2.1.1.1  
2    5ad4    4.1.3.3
```

I want to iterate over all rows of the `query dataframe`, search for the value of EC in that row in all rows of the `search dataframe`, and then if one result is found I want to add a new value in a third column in `query dataframe`. 
The result should be:

```
     PDB     EC       queryResult    
1    1uay    2.1.1.1  NA
2    5ad4    4.1.3.3  found_something
```

I thought I could do this with a function and `apply` but it does not work.

```
f = function(x) {
  EC_no =x[1]
  ifelse(length(grep(EC_no, searchDF$EC))>0,"found",NA)
}

data$queryResult <- apply(data,1,f)
```

However manually searching like this works:

```
> ifelse(length(grep("4.1.3.3", searchDF$EC))>0,"found",NA)
[1] "found"

> ifelse(length(grep("0.0.0.0", searchDF$EC))>0, "found",NA)
[1] NA
```

How could I get it to work in the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sapply`:

```
> df
               EC        name
1       2.1.1.233    helicase
2         4.1.3.3 phosphatase
3 1.3.2.1,2.5.4.1      lipase

> df2
   PDB      EC
1 1uay 2.1.1.1
2 5ad4 4.1.3.3

df2$queryResult <- sapply(df2$EC, function(x) ifelse(length(grep(x, df$EC))>0, "found", NA))

> df2
   PDB      EC queryResult
1 1uay 2.1.1.1        <NA>
2 5ad4 4.1.3.3       found
```

Comment: For me this still not yields the correct result. If `df2$EC` is `NA` then it prints  `found` in `df2$queryResult`. For other elements where there is a match in the searchDF it still prints NA. 

How is the use sapply and apply different here?

Comment: Can you provide example data for these cases?

Comment: Sorry. The issue was with the way I imported the data. I noticed this error when I tried to make a minimal example. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**
Since it is NOT exact matching - removed the previous suggestion. Instead, we can create a pattern match string to use to search.

```
searchdf <- data.frame(EC = c("2.1.1.233", "4.1.3.3", "1.3.2.1.2.5.4.1"), names = c("helicase", "phosphatase", "lipase"))
querydf <- data.frame(PBD = c("1uay", "5ad4"), EC = c("2.1.1.1", "4.1.3.3"))

querydf$found <- ifelse(querydf$EC %in% unique(grep(paste(querydf$EC, collapse="|"), searchdf$EC, value=TRUE)), "found", NA)

querydf
   PBD      EC found
1 1uay 2.1.1.1  <NA>
2 5ad4 4.1.3.3 found
```

Comment: Simplified the problem a bit. Exact matching is not usable in my case.

Comment: So in your function, why do you have an argument for `output` when that's not anywhere in your function.

Comment: This works as well. But I prefer they above way as I can adapt it for a more complex problem more easily. Thanks!